# Extracting a password from a String using regular expressions

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying to solve an exercise in which I have to print the password in a given text. The rules are:

> a password consists of digits and Latin upper- and lowercase letters;
> a password always follows the word "password" (it can be written in upper- or lowercase letters), but can be separated from it by any number of whitespaces and colon : characters.

My problem is that I need to make sure that the password is preceded by "password" and a random number of whitespaces and a colon, but I also must print the password only.

For example, if the input is:

```
My email javacoder@gmail.com with password     SECRET115. Here is my old PASSWORD: PASS111.
```

The output should be:

```
SECRET115

PASS111
```

I stumbled upon lookaheads and lookbehinds and tried them in my regex:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String text = scanner.nextLine();
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=password[\\s:]*)\\w*(?=\\W)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    if (!matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("No passwords found.");
    }
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }  
    }
}
```

This solution does print passwords only, but it also prints extra newlines for no reason. The output for the above input looked like this:

```
SECRET115



PASS111
```

Also, when I try to change the regex to `"(?<=password[\\s:]*)\\w{5,}(?=\\W)"` so that the password accepted be at least of length 5, the program outputs just:

```
PASS111
```

The other password is clearly longer than 5 characters, why was it left out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your password regex contains `\w*` the regex matches an empty string first. This match is not shown because you call `matcher.find()` in the `if` condition. When you use `\w{5}`, the first match is the `SECRET115`, and it is not displayed.

Use

```
\bpassword[\s:]*(\w+)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/vl7xaA/1)

**EXPLANATION**

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  password                 'password'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [\s:]*                   any character of: whitespace (\n, \r, \t,
                           \f, and " "), ':' (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
```

[Java code](https://tio.run/##hVLLTsMwELznK5aeHB6WcuDSqhKvSFSipSIVHBqETOKmLo4d2U7TCvXbi9s4RggJcpl4dzyzO8mKrMnFKv/Y71lZSWVgZQu4NozjJCNCUDUIfnUULegGj4nJln/0p8QYqsQgCDJOtIYxYQI@A7BPVb9zloE2xFhYS5ZDabsoMYqJYv4KRBU6dGQANwloh0MQtOmqKNlqQ0vMRDjo@EcZMHRjLNfdwsIeH5igyPPchFA5HHYVnMmyYpyiXpq@V3b4Rqp8nqa6/3qK0rQ5C3vnnnt7ncRvo0kST5LRbPQce3kXkF2txWFnhF0FHSb09BspOSUCFrIWuSUvCNe0azZLOw4gdxEvmMhR@J2Q3blNQdYGV3Z7w4UnF0rWFYpC7wTew6jaW@wcsgWgkyPhH/3eREIXjm4lcS/8KbcLdvv9eAvUfl9@/EUymVN1VRzOh5ihYWbpZVqr@PYpnkXRJYZ7qigwDeUWJM9hep0kL49Pd/3jWxRF@As):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String text = scanner.nextLine();
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\bpassword[\\s:]*(\\w+)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
Boolean found = false;
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    found = true;
}
if (!found) {
    System.out.println("No passwords found.");
}
```

Output:

```
SECRET115
PASS111
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the regex, `(?<=password|password:)\\s*(\\p{Alnum}+)` which is not only simple to understand but also gives you the result precisely.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=password|password:)\\s*(\\p{Alnum}+)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern
                .matcher("My email javacoder@gmail.com with password     SECRET115. Here is my old PASSWORD: PASS111.");

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
SECRET115
PASS111
```

**Explanation of the regex:**

1. `\p{Alnum}` matches an alphanumeric character. Check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) to learn more about it. Note that you should not use `\w` for your requirement because it also matches underscore(`_`) apart from alphabets and digits.
2. The regex uses the positive lookbehind to assert that `\\s*(\\p{Alnum}+)` should be followed by `(?<=password|password:)` i.e. `password` or `password:`
3. The desired result comes from `group(1)` which is specified as `(\\p{Alnum}+)`

If you are not comfortable with `\p{Alnum}`, you can use `[A-Za-z0-9]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The first match is eaten because of the matcher.find() call in the if condition. Only starting from the second match you produce output.

Answer (score 0):

Try   (?i)(password[\s:]*)(\w+)
and extract second group in every match
In java variable length lookbehind are not possible...

Answer (score 0):

```
private static final Pattern PASSWORD_PATTERN =
 Pattern.compile("password\\s*:?\\s*(?<password>[A-Za-z0-9]+)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

public static List<String> getAllPasswords(String str) {
    Matcher matcher = PASSWORD_PATTERN.matcher(str);
    List<String> passwords = new ArrayList<>();

    while (matcher.find()) {
        passwords.add(matcher.group("password"));
    }

    return passwords;
}
```

Demo you can find at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/SnPuqC/2)

Comment: As per the requirement, `a password consists of digits and Latin upper- and lowercase letters`. You have used `w+` which also selects underscore (`_`) in addition to letters and digits. You should use `\p{Alnum}+` or `[A-Za-z0-9]+`

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash fixed. This is details but still.